# A question related to bound of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be two sequences of unit vectors in a Hilbert space $H$. Assume that $\lim \sup |\langle x_n,y_n \rangle|\leq a <1$ for some $a\in [0,1)$. Let $(\alpha_n)$ and $(\beta_n)$ be two real sequences such that $\|z_n\|=\|\alpha_n x_n+\beta_n y_n\|=1$ for each $n$. To show that $(\alpha_n)$ and $(\beta_n)$ are bounded.

**Try:** For sufficiently large $n$, $|\langle x_n,y_n \rangle|\leq a$. Thus, for sufficiently large $n$, each $(\alpha_n,\beta_n)$ lies on the ellipse $x^2+y^2+2xy~Re~\langle x_n,y_n \rangle=1$. For sufficiently large $n$, each of these ellipse has major axis of length less than or equal to the length of the major axis, say $2b$, of the ellipse $x^2+y^2+2axy=1$. (I found it from plotting the graph in desmos graph). So for sufficiently large $n$, each $(\alpha_n,\beta_n)$ lies inside the circle of radius $b$.

My proof lacks analytical argument. And any help will be appreciated!